# php- is my code safe enough when using shell_exec()?

Tags: php, security, shell-exec, remotecommand

I am using `shell_exec` function on the following variables to execute commands on the shell:

1. `fname` (characters only)
2. `fpack`(characters only)
3. `email` (a valid email address)

My code is:

```
<?php

require_once 'connectionToDB.php';

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, filter_var(escapeshellarg($_POST['fname']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$fpack = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, filter_var(escapeshellarg($_POST['fpack']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, filter_var(escapeshellarg($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));

/** Verify name of applicaion **/
if(!ctype($fname)) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Application name must be in english alphabetical letters only'));
    die($op);
}
if(strlen($fname)>20) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Application name must be less than 20 characters'));
    die($op);
}

/** Verify name of package **/
if(!ctype($fpack)) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Package name must be in english alphabetical letters only'));
    die($op);
}
if(strlen($fpack)>20) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Package name must be less than 20 characters'));
    die($op);
}

/** Verify user's email **/
if (strlen($email)>50) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Email must be of less than 50 characters'));
    die($op);
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $op = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Please provide a valid email address.'));
    die($op);
}
```

As I said I am using `shell_exec` on these variables, I am scared of remote code execution. Is my code safe enough to prevent RCE?

Comment: There is no `ctype` function in standard PHP. Is it a custom function?

Comment: Generally, you have to differentiate between the data validation according to your data model (e. g., *email* should only be a valid e-mail address) and the proper handling of the data during processing (e. g., proper quoting/escaping command line parameters). These are two absolutely different and independent steps. You’re mixing them together.

Comment: [Same question on Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/82506/539)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/a/82521/43688